# cookies causing "unsecure content" warnings on google chrome?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies, https, protocols

If i visit the home page on my site (which uses code igniter) my homepage is using http,
Code igniter sets a cookie containing all the session info.

If I then click login, which is using https I get unsecure content warnings, and the only thing I can think of it being is the cookies as If I restart the browser then go straight to https://mysite.com/login then I get no unsecure content warnings.

How can I fix this (Note that the homepage cannot be https).

Comment: do you have a valid https ? did you bought it ? or you just added https to your domain name? click on the https in the navigation bar you will get more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error comes from content being served over http to a page that's supposed to be https. For example, an `<img>`, `<link>`, or `<script>`.

The thing with Codeigniter is that it's very likely you're using `base_url()` or `site_url()` for full absolute URLs to the embedded content, probably using http.

Here are some things you can do:

1. Use relative URL's, i.e. `<img src="/path/to/images.jpg">`
2. Don't specify a protocol. Example: `//example.com/path/to/image.jpg` More on this technique here: http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/
3. In the `__construct()` of the controller that you need to use https (or in the method that needs it), load a different config file that redefines your base url to use https. Note that it will be too late for any scripts/libraries that use the base url for html output before this config file is loaded.

If you load the page in IE, you should get a very nagging error message that will give you a list of all the content that was delivered insecurely to help you troubleshoot (other browsers should have this feature as well, but in IE it's especially prominent).

**EDIT**: Saw your note that there is nothing on the page being requested via http, only https, and the note about what happens when no cookies are present. My mistake, I just woke up - I should have read the question more thoroughly :p

Answer (score 0):

You are loading unsecure content (usually images/iframes) on your secure (https) login page.

What this means is that you are referencing a link to a page that is not secure (is not https). This will cause the error, and prompt users whether or not to load such content. It's a problem with the links to external content, not your cookies.

**Edit**: To (temporarily) fix the issue, find any links/references to external content and disable it for the time being, then visit your page and the prompt/error should go away.

To fix the issue, you'll have to download the content or use a file on your site to securely download the content for that page to use.

Comment: there is nothing on the page being requested via http, only https,